# cannot see wso2 api manager summarized tables

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have configured wso2 DAS 3.0.1, APIM 1.10 in my windows desktop machine and in data explorer i can see only API Manager event streams only but not API manager summarized tables. But in unix machine i can see all the tables including summarized tables. can you tell me why is this happening.[windows machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY1wV.png) [Unix machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uci6n.png)

Comment: Do you see any errors in WSO2 DAS wso2carbon.log?

Comment: i see this error: Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: o
rg/xerial/snappy/SnappyInputStream
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.sc

Comment: fyi. in windows i can pull statistics with those event tables.

Comment: Have you written any custom scripts for summarizing or any other ?